# No module named 'sklearn.neighbors.base' still existed after all the suggestions what I can take

Tags: python, python-3.x

I learned a lot of solutions from this website, but still cannot solve the problem. My code is as follows for your review:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import missingno as msno
import altair as alt
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
import plotly.express as px
from pandas.plotting import parallel_coordinates
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout
from scipy.spatial import distance
!pip install sklearn
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
from missingpy import MissForest
import sklearn.neighbors._base
sys.modules['sklearn.neighbors.base'] = sklearn.neighbors._base
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

And still shows the error:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors.base' I've tried to do the follows:

pip install -U imbalanced-learn ;
pip install -U scikit-learn

ans there was still of no use

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11280/2643854484.py in <module>
     26 from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
     27 from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
---> 28 from missingpy import MissForest
     29 import sklearn.neighbors._base
     30 sys.modules['sklearn.neighbors.base'] = sklearn.neighbors._base

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\missingpy\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .knnimpute import KNNImputer
      2 from .missforest import MissForest
      3 
      4 __all__ = ['KNNImputer', 'MissForest']

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\missingpy\knnimpute.py in <module>
     11 from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
     12 from sklearn.utils.validation import FLOAT_DTYPES
---> 13 from sklearn.neighbors.base import _check_weights
     14 from sklearn.neighbors.base import _get_weights
     15 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors.base'
```

Comment: Could you tell us the version of `scikit-learn` you have installed? `missingpy` has not been updated in a while and expects a very specific version of `scikit-learn`.

Comment: "missingpy has not been updated in a while and expects a very specific version of scikit-learn." what's that mean?

Comment: The latest one, not checked the version yet

Comment: sklearn version is 1.0.2

Comment: It seems the probelm is the missingpy version. what should I do now?

Answer (score 8):

Finally, I solved the problem!!

I should write this before import `missingpy`, not behind it.

```
import sklearn.neighbors._base
import sys
sys.modules['sklearn.neighbors.base'] = sklearn.neighbors._base
from missingpy import MissForest
```

done.