# How to import Missingpy in Python

Tags: python, random-forest

I have tried all the answers that has been posted on the forum but I keep getting thrown this error
How do I correct this error?

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Godfred King\Desktop\Python\titanic\mlingopractice.ipynb Cell 6 in <cell line: 4>()
      2 import sklearn.neighbors._base
      3 import sys
----> 4 from missingpy import MissForest
      5 sys.modules['sklearn.neighbors.base'] = sklearn.neighbors._base

File c:\Users\Godfred King\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\missingpy\__init__.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from .knnimpute import KNNImputer
      2 from .missforest import MissForest
      4 __all__ = ['KNNImputer', 'MissForest']

File c:\Users\Godfred King\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\missingpy\knnimpute.py:13, in <module>
     11 from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
     12 from sklearn.utils.validation import FLOAT_DTYPES
---> 13 from sklearn.neighbors.base import _check_weights
     14 from sklearn.neighbors.base import _get_weights
     16 from .pairwise_external import pairwise_distances

ImportError: cannot import name '_check_weights' from 'sklearn.neighbors._base' (c:\Users\Godfred King\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_base.py)
```

I have tried the responses posted here [No module named 'sklearn.neighbors.base' still existed after all the suggestions what I can take](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70923203/no-module-named-sklearn-neighbors-base-still-existed-after-all-the-suggestions)
but I get the same error

Comment: Are you sure about your import ? Checking https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py , there is nothing named `_check_weights` in the `neighbors._base` module.

Comment: Aren't you looking for https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/02ebf9e68fe1fc7687d9e1047b9e465ae0fd945e/sklearn/mixture/_gaussian_mixture.py#L21 ?

Comment: try this, first install `pip install sklearn` and then add this line `sys.modules['sklearn.neighbors.base'] = sklearn.neighbors._base` just below `import sklearn.neighbors._base`

Comment: or `scikit-learn` has some new changes, try upgrading it using `pip install -U scikit-learn`

Comment: `!pip install sklearn
import sys
import sklearn.neighbors._base
sys.modules['sklearn.neighbors.base'] = sklearn.neighbors._base
from missingpy import MissForest` THis is the code I am trying to run and that has been the error. I have tried all the suggestions but I still get the same error @EvilReboot

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who encounters the issue of not being able to import `missingpy`, try installing the following packages with specific versions:

```
scikit-learn==1.1.2
scipy==1.9.1
missingpy==0.2.0
```

You don't really need to install `sklearn`, which is a deprecated version of `scikit-learn`. Also, remember to add the following code when importing `missingpy`:

```
import sklearn.neighbors._base # this is from `scikit-learn` instead of `sklearn`
import sys
sys.modules['sklearn.neighbors.base'] = sklearn.neighbors._base
from missingpy import MissForest # remember to put this after sys.modules
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be correct,
try updating your packages,

Code Output:
[image: Code Output]

Comment: can I know the sklearn version you installed

Comment: @GodfredSakyi-Badu it's in the image brother